# arcpy pantoselected error

Tags: arcpy, indentationerror

I am trying to get an user input for getting a parcel name and pan the map to that selection. What am I doing wrong in the code below?

```
import arcpy

#Msg box to get parcel Name
parcel_Name = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
arcpy.AddMessage ("Loading parcel " + parcel_Name)

try:

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
    ssparcel = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapDoc, "ssparcel", df)[0]

    whereClause = "Name ='%s'" % parcel_Name
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(ssparcel, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
    df.extent = df.panToExtent(ssparcel.getSelectedExtent())
        #df.scale *= 1.5
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

except:

    arcpy.AddWarning ("Error")

...
```

Removed the "try" and got the following error:

Executing: Script "0002"
Start Time: Thu Jun 05 11:32:14 2014
Running script Script...
IndentationError: unexpected indent (abcd.py, line 9)
Failed to execute (Script).
Failed at Thu Jun 05 11:32:14 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)

Comment: Can you pull the code out of the `try/except` block so you can get the actual error being raised and add it to your question?

Comment: The Indentation Error is occurring if you removed the Try but did not remove the indentations. Python needs all of the code properly indented to work.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me in the Python window:

```py
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Prog*", df)[0]
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "OBJECTID=1")
df.panToExtent(lyr.getSelectedExtent())
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Or, the last two lines can be combined as (like you did):

```py
df.extent = df.panToExtent(lyr.getSelectedExtent())
```

**EDIT:** The difference I see with yours is the variable `mapDoc`.

How do I pass a string parameter obtained from user like "OBJECTID="&userinput?

Comment: please edit your answer, to remove the question. ask a new question. See the tour. http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and also good answers FAQ http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Concatenation in python is done like this: "a" + "b" --> "ab". Cast the user input to a string first via `str()`.